# Using Framework Entities, when Include a linked table then Orderby

Tags: entity-framework, silverlight-4.0

I have a query made in FrameWork Entities that uses a int id which is passed in, which brings back the correct Question from 1 table and also brings back the corresponding Answers from another table by using an Include.

What I want to happen is that the included answers are ordered by the id's. I have searched but not found an answer that works. The code below is my original query that works with a Orderby inserted. The Orderby achieves nothing.

How do I get the Answers in the order they are in the database, the Id's?

```
public Question GetQuestionById(int id)
{
    Question questions;

    using (var context = new Entities())
    {
        questions = context.Questions.Include("Answers").OrderBy(answer => answer.Id).First(question => question.Id == id);
        return questions;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should accept @jeroenh's answer below because the answer correct.

Answer (score 5):

You can't (to my knowledge)

```
questions = context.Questions.Include("Answers")
                   .OrderBy(answer => answer.Id)
                   .First(question => question.Id == id);
```

The parameter you pass to OrderBy here (`answer => answer.Id`) is misleading: you're ordering the questions, not the answers. To clarify, you could write it like this:

```
ObjectSet<Question> questions = context.Questions; 
IQueryable<Question> questionsWithAnswers = questions.Include("Answers");
IQueryable<Question> orderedQuestions = questionsWithAnswers
                                           .OrderBy(question => question.Id);
Question question = orderedQuestions.First(question => question.Id == id);
```

In order to do what you want, I believe you can only order after you query them from the database:

```
var question = context.Questions.Include("Answers").First(q => q.Id == id);

var answers = question.Answers.OrderBy(answer => answer.Id);
```

Another possibility might be to use an intermediate anonymous type:

```
var question = from q in context.Questions
               where q.Id == id
               select new {
                   Question = q, 
                   Answers = q.Answers.OrderBy(answer => answer.Id)
               }
```

Comment: It will work and your options are exactly the two only ways to get the result in one database roundtrips.